# Pandas - diagonal / shift

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for advice please.

In my DF below, I would like to subract the 'difference' column value (red square), from the value in 'trailing sl' column (blue square), but shifted to lag .shift(1).

So the new values would be:

```
1.08778 - 0.00115
1.08663 - 0.00077
1.08586 - 0.00059
etc
```

I've tried .loc with a .shift value, but that's not quite right.

```
df.loc[df.difference != np.nan, 'trailing_sl'] = df.trailing_sl.shift(1) - df.difference
```

I'm stuck tbh.

[image]

Any advice on a route forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, my answer was to make a cumulative sum series of the 'difference' column, and then subract the 'trailing_sl' value from the new series.

It seems to work, so far at least :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
m = df['difference'].notna()
df.loc[m, 'trailing_sl'] = df.trailing_sl.shift() - df['difference']
```

Or:

```
df['trailing_sl'] = df.trailing_sl.shift().sub(df['difference']).fillna(df['trailing_sl'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately the results aren't quite right either, but thank you for the reply. I will research diagonals in Pandas.